# Form submission in MVC using Ajax. Can't prevent default form submission

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to submit a form using Ajax in ASP.NET, everything works fine but I can't prevent default form submission using e.preventdefault() method.

This is my jquery ajax submission code :

```
 $('#submitBtn').on('click', function () {
    $('#addNewContact').submit(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (message) {
                console.log(message);
            },
            error: function (message) {
                console.log(message);
            }

        })


    })
})
```

Comment: change the type of `submitBtn` to normal button OR modify code to `$('#submitBtn').on('click', function (e) {` and `e.preventDefault();` within this outer click function.

Answer (score 2):

If `e.preventDefault()` is not working you can write - `return false;` - statement at the end of the function which performs the desired functionality and will prevent default form submission.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a form with id `addNewContact` and a submit button then you may register it using something like this:

```
$('#addNewContact').submit(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        // ...
    });

});
```

In your code, you've used `$(this).attr('action')` which means that, you are trying to use a form submit event but you did it wrong in your code. What you did is:

```
$('#submitBtn').on('click', function () { // Click handler registered

    $('#addNewContact').submit(function (e) { // Submit handler registered

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            // ...
        });

    });
});
```

So, your code should be as given below (for form submit event):

```
$('#addNewContact').submit(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (message) {
            console.log(message);
        },
        error: function (message) {
            console.log(message);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. The submit handler will be registered only if he clicks the button and that's not the expected behavior.