# Saving values of html table to database in ASP NET MVC and JQUERY/AJAX

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am building a Point of Sale system in ASP.NET MVC and I wish to save the content of the HTML table containing all the orders to the database.
I have tried sending it through JSON to the controller but it saves only the first row of the table and ignores the rest rows.

Also, asides the HTML table contents, I also have some data in textboxes that I want to save into the database though it will have to be manipulated first in the controller. Below is the code I have tried but it saves only the first row on the table and ignores others.

**the below is the Controller side code**

```
  public JsonResult InsertOrders(List<OrderDetail> orderDetails)
    {
        using (POSContext entities = new POSContext())
        {
            
            //Check for NULL.
            if (orderDetails == null)
            {
                orderDetails = new List<OrderDetail>();
            }

            //Loop and insert records.
            foreach (OrderDetail orderDetail in orderDetails)
            {
                orderDetail.Order_Date = WATTime;
                orderDetail.Cashier= User.Identity.Name;
                entities.OrderDetails.Add(orderDetail);
            }
            int insertedRecords = entities.SaveChanges();
            return Json(insertedRecords);
        }
    }
```

**Below is the frontend where I am passing the JSON to backend**

```
   ///////Save Transactions To Database// Still testing this line of codes
       
        $('#btnsavetransaction').click(function () {

            //Loop through the Table rows and build a JSON array.
            var orders = new Array();
            $("#tblCart tbody tr").each(function () {
                var row = $(this);
                var order = {};
                order.Item_ID = row.find("TD").eq(1).html();
                order.Item_Name = row.find("TD").eq(2).html();
                order.salesPrice = row.find("TD").eq(3).html();
                order.Qty = row.find("TD").eq(4).html();
                order.Amount = row.find("TD").eq(5).html();
                orders.push(order);
            });


            //Send the JSON array to Controller using AJAX.
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Transactions/Transactions/InsertOrders",
                data: JSON.stringify(orders),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) {
                    alert(r + " record(s) inserted.");
                }
            });


        });
```

It actually saves the first row but ignores other rows.

Then, I also have some data in textbox that I want to pass to the controller as well, since I have passed table as JSON, how can I pass the values of the textboxes as well?

Thank you.

**EDIT : The below is the full View**

```
@model POS_Web.Models.POSModel.Cartdummy
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Point Of Sales";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<div class="w3-container" style="padding-left:10px">
    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 w3-card-4" style="padding-left:40px; padding-right:20px">
        <h2 class="w3-center"><strong>Point Of Sales </strong></h2>

        <div class="w3-row">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("PointOfSales", "Transactions", new { area = "Transactions" }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="form-horizontal">

                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                @*@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)*@
                @*@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.New_Quantity)*@


                <div class="w3-responsive w3-row">
                    @*<h2 class="w3-center"><strong>All Items in Stock </strong></h2>*@
                    <table id="tblItems" class="table w3-table-all w3-hoverable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>

                                <th>Item ID</th>
                                <th>Item Category</th>
                                <th>Item Name</th>
                                <th>Cost Price</th>
                                <th>Sales Price</th>
                                <th>Quantity</th>
                                <th>Reorder Level</th>
                                <th>Item Discontinued?</th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody></tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <div class="w3-row">
                    <div class="w3-col w3-third">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Item_ID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })

                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Item_ID, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Item ID", @class = "form-control", @readonly = "true" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Item_ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="w3-col w3-third">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Item_Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })

                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Item_Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Item Name", @class = "form-control", @readonly = "true" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Item_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="w3-col w3-third">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Sales_Price, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })

                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Sales_Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Price", @class = "form-control", @readonly = "true" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sales_Price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                        </div>
                    </div>



                </div>
                <div class="w3-row">
                    <div class="w3-col w3-third">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Qty, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })

                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Qty, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Qty", @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Qty, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w3-col w3-third">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Amount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })

                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Amount", @class = "form-control", @readonly = "true" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Amount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="w3-col w3-third">
                        <div class="form-group">

                            <input type="button" id="btnAddToCart" value="Add To Cart" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" />

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="w3-row">

                    <h3 class="w3-center"><strong>Shopping Cart </strong></h3>
                </div>

                <div class="w3-responsive w3-row">
                  
                    <table id="tblCart" class="table w3-table-all">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Remove From Cart</th>
                                <th>Item ID</th>
                                <th>Item Name</th>

                                <th>Sales Price</th>
                                <th>Qty</th>
                                <th>Amount</th>


                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody></tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="w3-col w3-third">


                </div>

                <div class="w3-col w3-third">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Total_Amount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })

                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Total_Amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Total Amount", @class = "form-control", @readonly = "True" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Total_Amount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Amount_Tendered, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })

                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount_Tendered, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Amount Tendered", @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Amount_Tendered, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Change_Received, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })

                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Change_Received, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Change Received", @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Change_Received, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                    </div>





                </div>

                <div class="w3-col w3-third">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Payment_Method, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })

                        @Html.DropDownList("Payment_Method", new List<SelectListItem>{
                               new SelectListItem{ Text="Cash", Value="Cash"},
                               new SelectListItem{ Text="Bank Transfer", Value="Bank Transfer"},
                               new SelectListItem{ Text="POS", Value="POS"}

                               }, "--- Select Payment Method ---", new { @class = "form-control" }
                               )
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Payment_Method, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customer_ID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })

                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Customer_ID, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Customer ID", @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Customer_ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                    </div>


                    <br />
                    <div class="form-group">

                        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="submitbtn" />

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">

                        <input type="button" id="btnsavetransaction" value="Save Transaction" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" />

                    </div>

                </div>


                <hr />



            </div>
                }
            </div>

    </div>


</div>

        @section Scripts {
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
       @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
       @Styles.Render("~/Content/cssjqryUi")
       @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
       @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")
       @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.date.js")
       @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")
       @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")


    @*<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>*@
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Declaring the Total Amount First
        var totalAmount = 0;
        var itemDiscontinued = null;
        var stock = 0;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            

            $('#submitbtn').click(function (e) {
                $('#errorWithdraw').css('display', 'none');
                if (!$('#form').valid()) {
                    alert('Some Input Fields has Not Been Filled Correctly');
                    return false;
                } else if ($('#form').valid()) {



                    var x = confirm("Are you sure to Save this Transaction?"); //confirm text
                    if (x == true) {  //checking whether user clicked ok or cancel
                        $('.spinner').css('display', 'block');  //if clicked ok spinner shown)


                    } else {  //else if clicked cancel spinner is hidden
                        $('.spinner').css('display', 'none');
                        return false //stops further process
                    }
                }

            });



            //Table listing all categories and allows filtering
            $(function () {
                var oTable;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/StockManagement/StockManagement/Items",
                    data: '{}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        var customers = eval(response);
                        oTable = $("#tblItems").DataTable({
                            bLengthChange: true,
                            lengthMenu: [[5], [5]],
                            bFilter: true,
                            bSort: true,
                            bPaginate: true,
                            data: customers,
                            columns: [

                                { 'data': 'Item_ID' },
                                { 'data': 'Item_category' },
                                { 'data': 'Item_Name' },
                                { 'data': 'Cost_Price' },
                                { 'data': 'Sales_Price' },
                                { 'data': 'Quantity' },
                                { 'data': 'Reorder_Level' },
                                { 'data': 'Item_Discontinued' },


                            ]
                        });
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });

                $('#Item_Name').keyup(function () {
                    oTable.search($(this).val()).draw();
                })
            });

            //Making the Table clickable
            $(function () {

                $('#tblItems').on('click', 'tr', function () {
                    var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");

                    var itemID = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text(); // get current row 1st TD value
                    var itemName = currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").text(); // get current row 2nd TD
                    //  var oldQty = currentRow.find("td:eq(5)").text(); // get current row 5th TD
                    var salesprice = currentRow.find("td:eq(4)").text(); // get current row 5th TD
                    itemDiscontinued = currentRow.find("td:eq(7)").text();  // getting the Discontinued status of the item selected
                    stock = currentRow.find("td:eq(5)").text();  // getting the Stock of the Item selected

                    $('#Item_ID').val(itemID);
                    $('#Item_Name').val(itemName);
                    //  $('#Old_Quantity').val(oldQty);
                    $('#Sales_Price').val(salesprice);


                });

            });


            //The Cart table Jquery
            $(function () {

                //calculating the Amount when Qty is entered
                $('#Qty').keyup(function () {
                    var Qty = $('#Qty').val();
                    if ($('#Item_ID').val() == '' || $('#Item_ID').val() == undefined) {
                        alert('Please Select an Item First');
                        $('#Qty').val('');
                        return false;
                    }
                    var salesPrice = parseFloat($('#Sales_Price').val());
                    var amount = Qty * salesPrice;
                    $('#Amount').val(amount);
                })

            });


            //Jquery for the AddToCart Button
            $('#btnAddToCart').click(function () {
                var itemID = $('#Item_ID').val();
                var itemName = $('#Item_Name').val();
                var salesprice = parseFloat($('#Sales_Price').val());
                var Qty = $('#Qty').val();
                var amount = $('#Amount').val();

                var newstock = stock - Qty;


                if ($('#Item_ID').val() == '' || $('#Item_ID').val() == undefined) {
                    alert('Please Select an Item to Add to Cart');
                    return false;
                }

                if ($('#Qty').val() == '' || $('#Qty').val() == undefined || $('#Qty').val() == 0) {
                    alert('Please Enter the Qty of The Item Been Purchased');
                    return false;
                }

                if ($('#Sales_Price').val() == '' || $('#Sales_Price').val() == undefined || $('#Sales_Price').val() == 0) {
                    alert('Please Enter the Qty of The Item Been Purchased');
                    return false;
                }

                if (itemDiscontinued == 'Yes' ) {
                    alert('The Item Selected has been Discontinued and cannot be sold');
                    $('#Item_ID').val('');
                    $('#Item_Name').val('');
                    $('#Sales_Price').val('');
                    $('#Qty').val('');
                    $('#Amount').val('');
                    return false;
                }

                if (newstock < 0) {
                    alert('The Qty of ' + $('#Item_Name').val() + ' Selected to be purchased is more than what is in store, Please replenish item');
                    $('#Item_ID').val('');
                    $('#Item_Name').val('');
                    $('#Sales_Price').val('');
                    $('#Qty').val('');
                    $('#Amount').val('');
                    return false;
                }


                //Check if the Item is already in Cart////////////////////////////
                var $tds = $('#tblCart tr > td:nth-child(2)').filter(function () {
                    return $.trim($(this).text()) == itemID;
                });
                if ($tds.length != 0) {
                    alert("Item already in Cart");
                    $('#Item_ID').val('');
                    $('#Item_Name').val('');
                    $('#Sales_Price').val('');
                    $('#Qty').val('');
                    $('#Amount').val('');
                    return false;
                }

                /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                //Bild up the table row
                var table =
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td><button  type='button' name='record' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='deleterow(this)'> Remove </td>" +
                    "<td>" + itemID + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + itemName + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + salesprice + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + Qty + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + amount + "</td>" +
                    "<tr>";
                totalAmount += Number(amount);
                $('#Total_Amount').val(totalAmount);

                $('#tblCart tbody').append(table);
                //Empty the Textboxes to allow for new item
                $('#Item_ID').val('');
                $('#Item_Name').val('');
                $('#Sales_Price').val('');
                $('#Qty').val('');
                $('#Amount').val('');
            });




            ///////Save Transactions To Database// Still testing this line of codes
           
            $('#btnsavetransaction').click(function () {

                //Loop through the Table rows and build a JSON array.
                var orders = new Array();
                $("#tblCart tbody tr").each(function () {
                    var row = $(this);
                    var order = {};
                    order.Item_ID = row.find("TD").eq(1).html();
                    order.Item_Name = row.find("TD").eq(2).html();
                    order.salesPrice = row.find("TD").eq(3).html();
                    order.Qty = row.find("TD").eq(4).html();
                    order.Amount = row.find("TD").eq(5).html();
                    orders.push(order);
                });


                //Send the JSON array to Controller using AJAX.
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Transactions/Transactions/InsertOrders",
                    //data: JSON.stringify(orders),
                    data: JSON.stringify({ orderDetails: orders }),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (r) {
                        alert(r + " record(s) inserted.");
                    }
                });


            });

            
            


            


        });

        ////Function to Delete Row from Cart
        function deleterow(e) {
            var amount = parseFloat($(e).parent().parent().find('td:last').text(), 10);
            totalAmount -= amount;
            $('#Total_Amount').val(totalAmount);
            $(e).parent().parent().remove();
        }


        function showSpinner() {
            $('.spinner').css('display', 'block');  //if clicked ok spinner shown
        }


    </script>

}
```

Comment: check in InsertOrders, do you get the list of order details?

Comment: You either have to save each order details object inside the foreach or do an add range on the list of objects and add them at once.

Comment: @urlreader, I breakpoint the code but it is only one row been passed inside to the controller.

Comment: @GHDevOps, What I am doing inside the foreach is saving each other details. Or am I doing it the wrong way?

Comment: If only one row is coming in then it's your stringify. The easiest way to do this in MVC is to use a form with a submit button. That way your model is automatically serialized back to the controller. If you need to do an ajax, hook up the submit form action in jQuery, prevent the defaults, then use ajax to post back. Your $(this) reference should make it easier to pass back to the server.

Comment: @GHDevOps, Yes, I have a submit button but I am not sure of the way to serialize the table content in form of array back to the controller. Do you have a resource or sample you can point me to? Infact, the Submit button would have been ideal as I would have access to my other textboxes easily but if not through that, ajax can also be used. Thank you.

Comment: @mantics it would be easier for you  to use  a submit button. Can you show the view pls?

Comment: See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40837302/form-submission-in-mvc-using-ajax-cant-prevent-default-form-submission

Comment: You have a button click function. You want a form submit function. The key is $(this).serialize() which will do what your stringify is trying to do.

Comment: @GHDevOps  Okay, so with this, I can remove the JSON.Stringify line from the code right?

Comment: @Serge, I have updated the post to contain the view

Comment: I got the issue resolved. The issue was how I was building my Table Row. I will post the answer shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// jQuery for the AddToCart Button
$('#btnAddToCart').click(function () {
    var itemID = $('#Item_ID').val();
    var itemName = $('#Item_Name').val();
    var salesprice = parseFloat($('#salesPrice').val()).toFixed(2);
    var Qty = $('#Qty').val();
    var amount = $('#Amount').val();
    var newstock = stock - Qty;


    if ($('#Item_ID').val() == '' || $('#Item_ID').val() == undefined) {
        alert('Please Select an Item to Add to Cart');
        return false;
    }

    if ($('#Qty').val() == '' || $('#Qty').val() == undefined || $('#Qty').val() == 0) {
        alert('Please Enter the Qty of The Item Been Purchased');
        return false;
    }

    if ($('#salesPrice').val() == '' || $('#salesPrice').val() == undefined || $('#salesPrice').val() == 0) {
        alert('Please Enter the Qty of The Item Been Purchased');
        return false;
    }

    if (itemDiscontinued == 'Yes') {
        alert('The Item Selected has been Discontinued and cannot be sold');
        $('#Item_ID').val('');
        $('#Item_Name').val('');
        $('#salesPrice').val('');
        $('#Qty').val('');
        $('#Amount').val('');
        return false;
    }

    if (newstock < 0) {
        alert('The Qty of ' + $('#Item_Name').val() + ' Selected to be purchased is more than what is in store, Please replenish item');
        $('#Item_ID').val('');
        $('#Item_Name').val('');
        $('#salesPrice').val('');
        $('#Qty').val('');
        $('#Amount').val('');
        return false;
    }

    // Check if the Item is already in Cart
    var $tds = $('#tblCart tr > td:nth-child(2)').filter(function () {
        return $.trim($(this).text()) == itemID;
    });
    if ($tds.length != 0) {
        alert("Item already in Cart");
        $('#Item_ID').val('');
        $('#Item_Name').val('');
        $('#salesPrice').val('');
        $('#Qty').val('');
        $('#Amount').val('');
        return false;
    }

    // Build up the table row
    var tbody = $('#tblCart tbody');
    var tr = $('<tr></tr>');
    tr.append("'<td><button  type='button' name='record' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='deleterow(this)'> Remove </td>'")
    tr.append('<td>' + itemID + '</td>');
    tr.append('<td>' + itemName + '</td>');
    tr.append('<td>' + salesprice + '</td>');
    tr.append('<td>' + Qty + '</td>');
    tr.append('<td>' + amount + '</td>');
    tbody.append(tr);

    totalAmount += Number(amount);
    $('#Total_Amount').val(parseFloat(totalAmount).toFixed(2));

    // Empty the Textboxes to allow for new item
    $('#Item_ID').val('');
    $('#Item_Name').val('');
    $('#salesPrice').val('');
    $('#Qty').val('');
    $('#Amount').val('');
});

// Checkout and Save Transactions To Database
$('#btnCheckOut').click(function() {
    // First check if the TableCart is not empty 
    if ($('#tblCart tr').length <= 1) {
        alert('The Cart is Empty, Please add Items to Cart');
        return false;
    }

    if ($('#Amount_Tendered').val() == '' || $('#Amount_Tendered').val() == undefined || $('#Amount_Tendered').val() <= 0) {
        alert('Please Enter the Amount Tendered by Customer');
        return false;
    }

    if ($('#Payment_Method').val() == '' || $('#Payment_Method').val() == undefined) {
        alert('Please Select the Payment Method');
        return false;
    }

    var totalAmount = parseFloat($('#Total_Amount').val());
    var changeReceived = parseFloat($('#Change_Received').val());

    if (changeReceived < 0 ) {
        alert('The Amount Tendered Cannot be Less than Total Amount');
        return false;
    }

    finalPayment();  //Call the finalpayment method
    EmptyControls(); //Calling the Empty control mehod
    loaddata();  //Items to be reloaded
});

// Function to Delete Row from Cart
function deleterow(e) {
    var amount = parseFloat($(e).parent().parent().find('td:last').text(), 10);
    totalAmount -= amount;
    $('#Total_Amount').val(totalAmount);
    $(e).parent().parent().remove();
}

//Function to send cart table to controller
function finalPayment() {
    var totalAmount = $('#Total_Amount').val();
    var paymentMethod = $('#Payment_Method').val();
    var amountTendered = $('#Amount_Tendered').val();
    var changeReceived = $('#Change_Received').val();
    var customerID = $('#Customer_ID').val();
    var orderdetails = new Array();

    $('#tblCart tr:not(:first)').each(function() {
        var row = $(this);
        var orderdetail = {};
        orderdetail.Item_ID = row.find("TD").eq(1).html();
        orderdetail.Item_Name = row.find("TD").eq(2).html();
        orderdetail.salesPrice = row.find("TD").eq(3).html();
        orderdetail.Qty = row.find("TD").eq(4).html();
        orderdetail.Amount = row.find("TD").eq(5).html();
        orderdetails.push(orderdetail);
    });

    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Transactions/Transactions/InsertOrders",
        //data: JSON.stringify(orderdetails),
        data: JSON.stringify({
            orderdetails: orderdetails,
            totalAmount: totalAmount,
            paymentMethod: paymentMethod,
            amountTendered: amountTendered,
            changeReceived: changeReceived,
            customerID: customerID
        }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Something went wrong, processing not completed");
        }
    });
}
```